# Spark worker node doesn't see added files

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have problem in running Java Spark application on my local machine. I'm running Spark master and 1 spark worker node as docker images with below config:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  spark:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_USER=spark
    ports:
      - '8010:8080'
      - '7077:7077'
    network_mode: bridge
  spark-worker:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://172.17.0.2:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=8G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_USER=spark
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
      - '65040:65040'
    network_mode: bridge
```

My local java app which is driver itself is configured as below:

```
 SparkConf conf =
                new SparkConf()
                        .setAppName("Simple Application")
                        .set("spark.driver.port", "65040")
                        .set("spark.driver.host", "192.168.18.15")
                        .set("spark.files.overwrite", "true")
                        .setMaster("spark://localhost:7077");

        sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf);
        String path = getClass().getResource("/addresses.csv").getPath();

        sparkContext.addFile(path);
        sparkContext.addedFiles();
        spark = new SparkSession(sparkContext);
        
        Dataset<Row> csv = spark.read().csv(SparkFiles.get("addresses.csv"));
```

master/workers and local app are communicating without problems, but there is problem with accessing `addresses.csv` file on workers, they are trying to access it using my local machine path, as in worker logs bellow:
`23/09/19 08:44:09 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) org.apache.spark.SparkFileNotFoundException: File file:/C:/Users/patry/AppData/Local/Temp/spark-fc24a898-45ad-47fe-bf10-41c109a8c46c/userFiles-ab6c8b5c-fc69-4f75-9627-7639860df8bf/addresses.csv does not exist` 
Any idea how i can upload and process my file at worker node without using HDFS?

I've tried to use different paths, ways of passing file to app, but without success

Answer (score 0):

While submitting the Spark application, you can include files to distribute. These files are submitted and placed on each worker's working directory. Obviously this isn't a good approach with large files; only small files should be distributed this way which aren't well suited for storage on HDFS or an equivalent storage.

I couldn't find the full list of arguments that are available with `spark-submit` from the official docs in a hurry, but I found a link from [CDP docs](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.7/running-spark-applications/topics/spark-submit-options.html).

```
spark-submit ./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options, here you can place --files <filepath/name>
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```